# No Listner is working on ListView

Tags: android, listview, position

I have set 2 to 3 listner on my Listview but no listner is working(But at a time a applied any 1 listner only.) i am using custom Adapter.I successfully got the data in listview every time means the object is not blank. but on tap on row i am not able to perform any action. I am using the code below. i also tried onItemSelectedListner but this is also not working.

```
MyAdapter myadptr = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(myadptr);


         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
         int arg2, long arg3) {
         Toast.makeText(ContactBookActivity.this,
         " inside setOnItemClickListener ", 300).show();
         }
         });
```

on logcat i got this 
[image]

can any on tell me why is this happening,because i am not using this code first time. In my other projects same code works for me.Please Help !!

**EDIT**

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflatList.size() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflatList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = lf.inflate(R.layout.importlist_inflator, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.in_ll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.in_ll);
        holder.im = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infltimg);
        holder.txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        holder.phn_import = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.phn_import);
        holder.eid_import = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.eid_import);
        convertView.setEnabled(true);
        // inflatList = dbh.reteriveContactInfo();

        int indx = 0;
        String did = inflatList.get(position).get(indx).toString();
        String name = inflatList.get(position).get(++indx).toString();
        // txtname.setText(inflatList.get(position).get(indx).toString());
        holder.phn_import.setText(inflatList.get(position).get(++indx)
                .toString());
        holder.eid_import.setText(inflatList.get(position).get(++indx)
                .toString());

        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                (byte[]) inflatList.get(position).get(++indx));
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        holder.im.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        holder.txtname.setText(name);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: do you have buttons in your rows?

Comment: can you post MyAdapter code?

Comment: Do you have any other views in the listview which you made clickable ?

Comment: No I have 4 textViews and 1 image in single row.don't have any button.

Comment: @Akanksha: are those views clickable?

Comment: Ok I have posted MyAdaptor code also here. and you can see that no other view is clickable. i want to perform  different action on tap of row.

Comment: Why don't you override onListItemClick() ???

Comment: Because to override it , i have to extends ListActivity and i am writing this inside Asynk task so no place to extend another class , any other way?

Comment: To your parent layout of your row view add this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this line in my inflator xml.

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in parent Layout,

and  android:focusable="false" in all imageView.

And now my code is working fine. Thanks to all of you for help.

Comment: android:focusable="true" is the culprit then.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you the perfect reason but below is what I used to solve the problem.

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

I have `Button` inside the listview which was consuming the click event as I guessed.So in your case it might be the `ImageView` that you used.

**EDIT**

There is a alternate way to make the row clickable also.Do something like below,

```
 convertView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: where to use it inside getview i have to cast it like:-((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) convertView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() and it throws class cast exception

Comment: @Akanksha: Sorry for my mistake.You just have to use a simple onClick Listner.See the edit now

Comment: By this i can't get the position and to perform different action i need position.

Comment: @Akanksha:I guess getView() of Adapter comes with a position as parameter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36544/discussion-between-user2012-and-akanksha)